# mvc asp.net web Ipad remove telephone number link

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, ipad

When i run the ipad safari in kiosk mode the telephone number link appears which is annoying. reason being we are running ipad in kisok mode and don't want user to add contacts etc.

is there any way I can completely disable the Add Contact link in ipad? I tried metatag which works on normal browser but comes back on **add to home screen** (kiosk mode).

Thanks heaps.